# Adding Columns if they exist in the Dataframe: pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I have  a Dataframe, where I want to add three columns and make it one, and I want it for the columns which exits in the data frame. so for example, I want to add following columns

```
List_ID=['ID1','ID2','ID3'] 
df # Df is the data frame
```

I am trying following for summing up the "if exists" columns, but not able to.

```
ID=sum[[col for col in list_ID if col in df.columns]]
```

And explaining ID1, ID2 columns they can be like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A', '', 'C', ' '],'Column 2':[' ', 'F', ' ', '']})  
and my new column ID will look like 

In[34]: a=df['Column 1'] + (df['Column 2'])

In[35]: a

   Out[35]: 
    0    A 
    1    F
    2    C 
    3
```

All suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC one possible solution is [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) wtihespaces:

```
a=df['Column 1'].str.strip() + df['Column 2'].str.strip()
print (a)
0    A
1    F
2    C
3     
dtype: object
```

More general solution is first filter column names:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['    A', '', 'C', ' '],
                   'ID2':[' ', 'F', ' ', ''], 
                   'ID5':['T', 'E', ' ', '']}) 
print (df)
     ID1 ID2 ID5
0      A       T
1          F   E
2      C        
3      

List_ID=['ID1','ID2','ID3'] 
cols = df.columns[df.columns.isin(List_ID)]
print (cols)
Index(['ID1', 'ID2'], dtype='object')

#there are whitespaces
print (df[cols].sum(axis=1))
0        A 
1         F
2        C 
3          
dtype: object
```

And then you need apply function `strip` for each column with list comprehension, [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) output list and last [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) by columns (`axis=1`)

```
print (pd.concat([df[c].str.strip() for c in df[cols]], axis=1).sum(axis=1))
0    A
1    F
2    C
3
```

EDIT by comment:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[15.3, 12.1, 13.2, 10.0],
                   'ID2':[7.0, 7.7, 2, 11.3], 
                   'ID5':[10, 15, 3.1, 2.2]}) 

print (df)
    ID1   ID2   ID5
0  15.3   7.0  10.0
1  12.1   7.7  15.0
2  13.2   2.0   3.1
3  10.0  11.3   2.2

List_ID=['ID1','ID2','ID3']
cols = df.columns[df.columns.isin(List_ID)]
print (cols)
Index(['ID1', 'ID2'], dtype='object')
```

```
#summed floats
print (df[cols].sum(axis=1))
0    22.3
1    19.8
2    15.2
3    21.3
dtype: float64

#cast float to string and sum
print (df[cols].astype(str).sum(axis=1))
0     15.37.0
1     12.17.7
2     13.22.0
3    10.011.3
dtype: object

#cast float to int, then to str, sum, then removed float 0 by cast to int and last to str
print (df[cols].astype(int).astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str))
0     157
1     127
2     132
3    1011
dtype: object

#cast float to int, then to str and concanecate by join
print (df[cols].astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1))
0     157
1     127
2     132
3    1011
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, for my particular problem, the sum is not working, it adding the values considering them as float. how can I convert filtered columns astype(str) or bring them in' ' and then sum

Comment: I think you can use `(pd.concat([df[c].str.strip() for c in df[cols].astype(str)], axis=1).sum(axis=1))`

Comment: both of the last solutions showing this error, really close, Just missing something "raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Comment: I add another sample and some examples of sums. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you so Much Jezrael, it is really helpful